# Migrating particular TCP Connection using CRIU tools

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, migration

Is it possible to migrate a single and particular TCP connection inside a running process in one machine to another machine using CRIU tools in Linux?

What I want is to dump a particular TCP Connection information in a memory and transfer this information to a peer machine. Inside this machine, I will use the dumped information to recreate the the migrated TCP connection. Does anyone have an example or tutorial in c language?

I am aware about different solutions like SockMi which provides Kernel Module + User Space APIs to migrate a certain TCP Socket. However, I want to use CRIU tools since it is part of Linux Mainline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now we only have the TCP migration functionality integrated into CRIU tool. It sits in the sk-tcp.c file, the whole TCP-repair code is there, though it's bound to the rest of CRIU.

On the other hand, we've been asked for TCP-only migration for quite a while, it's possible to pull this code into smth like libcriutcp.so, but it will require patching. You're welcome to participate to the https://github.com/xemul/criu/issues/72